# SQLite greater/less than operator giving false results

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, logic

I have the following SQLite query. It is intended to delete all entries where the time has not been updated in the past three seconds.

```
$expireTime = time() - 3;
$dbh->query("DELETE FROM `whois_online` WHERE (strftime('%s', `time`) > $expireTime)");
```

This query does not return any entries in the table, even though it should. However, changing the `>` to `<` causes the entires to appear, even though the numbers it is comparing should not let this happen.

If I explicitly replace `expireTime` with a number:

```
sqlite> SELECT strftime('%s', `time`) from whois_online WHERE (strftime('%s', `time`) > 1400005440);
```

I get the following result:

```
1400005363
1400005365
1400005368
1400005443
```

This is clearly not logically correct, as all these numbers are less than 1400005440. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strftime()` returns a *string*, not an integer. You need to use `CAST()` to convert the type.

```
SELECT CAST(strftime('%s', `time`) AS integer)
FROM whois_online
WHERE CAST(strftime('%s', `time`) AS integer) > 1400005440;
```